# JBOSS latest version

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am going to start a new enterprise application. Which version I wanted to use?
Is it EAP 6.2.0 GA(EAP built from AS 7.3) or JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final or Wildfly 8.1.0.Final? I am very confused about these versions. when do i have to download EAP 6.2.0?

Also, why wildfly is not avaialbe on http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/? why?
I was having the impression that wildfly and jboss8 as are same. If both are same,
why it is not avalible in the downloads of above link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the community version of JBoss has been renamed to Wildfly and can be found here: http://wildfly.org/downloads/. EAP 6.2 is the commercial version of JBoss provided by RedHat for which you get professional support by them.

Which version you choose depends on your requirements and whether you are willing to spend money for it ;) But if you are going with the community version, it wouldn't make sense to start with JBoss AS 7 since Wildfly 8 provides Java EE 7 support, JBoss AS 7 not. I've recently migrated a huge industry-strength project to Wildfly and am very surprised by the new application server. Nevertheless, with my current experience, I would recommend to go with EAP and professional support for large projects that utilize the whole Java EE stack. The only drawback there is that EAP 6 doesn't support Java EE 7 yet.

Comment: If you could provide more details about why you'd suggest EAP for large projects, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Jboss EAP is Red Hat product while wildfly is community version. Latest EAP version available currently is EAP 7.1.2, you will have to buy Red Hat subscription to use the same. Wildfly is opensource community version for the same, which you download and use freely.

Which version to be used will depend completely on your project requirement and budget. EAP would be more stable and tested product which can be used for critical production applications, also Red Hat will provide complete support if you purchase the subscription.

But if you have budget constraints and want to use free application server wildfly can be used.